# AttributeError: type object 'ListViewSet' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a scrumboard django app which basically has cards and lists in it. I'm unable to solve the following issue.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors 
<locals>.wrapper
at 0x0000000003DF7C80>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)

...
urlpatterns = router.urls
File "C:\Users\...\lib\site- 
packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 101, in urls
    self._urls = self.get_urls()
File "C:\Users\...\lib\site- 
packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 363, in get_urls
    urls = super(DefaultRouter, self).get_urls()
File "C:\Users\...\lib\site- 
packages\rest_framework\routers.py", line 261, in get_urls
    routes = self.get_routes(viewset)
File "C:\Users\...lib\site-packages\rest_framework\routers.py", 
line 176, in get_routes
    extra_actions = viewset.get_extra_actions()
AttributeError: type object 'ListViewSet' has no attribute 
'get_extra_actions'
```

Following is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
class  List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return "List : {}".format(self.name) # returns list values

class Card(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True) 
    list = models.ForeignKey(
        List, 
        related_name = "card",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT
    ) 
    story_points = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = True)
    business_value = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Card : {}".format(self.title)
```

My api.py where my viewset is defined

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from drf_multiple_model.views import ObjectMultipleModelAPIView
from .serializers import ListSerializer, CardSerializer
from .models import List, Card

class ListViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = List.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer


class CardViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Card.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CardSerializer

class ListViewSet(ObjectMultipleModelAPIView):
    querylist = [
        {
            'queryset': List.objects.all(), 
            'serializer_class': ListSerializer
        },
        {
            'queryset': Card.objects.all(), 
            'serializer_class': CardSerializer
        }
    ]
```

urls.py file where the exception is.

```
from .api import ListViewSet, CardViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'lists', ListViewSet, base_name='List')
router.register(r'cards', CardViewSet, base_name='Card')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I'm very new to django and I'm developing this with the help of a tutorial. I have been trying to find solution for this but I was unlucky with the solutions so I have posted it here.

Many Thanks.

Edit:
serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import List, Card

class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Card
        fields = '__all__'

class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = '__all__'
```

Versions,
Django==2.1.2
djangorestframework==3.8.2

Comment: can you add `ListSerializer` class?

Comment: You have two classes named `ListViewSet`. That's a problem right there. Also you are using some library called `drf_multiple_model`. Are you sure you are using it correctly? If `ListViewSet` is not a subclass of `ModelViewSet`, you can't use `router.register` with it.

Comment: @JPG i have added the class

Comment: @HåkenLid thank you for your comments. I was trying to combine two models and get a single JSON api that's why I was using `drf_multiple_model' library. I think i was not using that library properly. I commented out that code now it's back to normal  I shall find some other way to get a single JSON api file

Comment: You might be able to use it, but you can't use it with `router.register`. Instead, create a regular django route for that view and append to the `urlpatterns` list. See the drf docs about [generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/). You can keep using `route.register` for your ModelViewSet classes.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most likely cause here is that `django-rest-multiple-models` `ObjectMultipleModelAPIView` is not a subclass of `ViewSet`, it is a subclass of `GenericAPIView`, and the `get_extra_actions` method is defined on rest frameworks `ViewSetMixin` class (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/3.8.2/rest_framework/viewsets.py#L146)

You should update the `ObjectMultipleModelAPIView` to `ObjectMultipleModelAPIViewSet` and it should hopefully work with the `DefaultRouter`